# Does Liouville theory have modular invarinace?

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory

The liouville theory was very similar to the free theory but with the introduction of interaction. However, the method to approach the question seemed to be some what different from that of the free theory. Especially, the modular invariance proprieties were rarely discussed. From the scratch it seemed that the conformal map from a plane to a tours should still work and thus the modular invariance should hold. However, the continuous bulk spectrum seemed to indicate difference to that of the minimal model. Also, with the introduction of the interaction term characterized by $\mu$, it's not obvious if it still make sense to talk about the modular invariance, unless $\mu$ were mapped to the dual $\tilde \mu$ through manifestation.

Does Liouville theory have modular invarinace?

Comment: Assuming you mean [Liouville field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_field_theory), I'm not really sure what the question is: Liouville field theory is a conformal field theory, and conformal field theories have modular invariance. It is not really clear what you mean by $\mu$ or $\tilde{\mu}$, nor what "through manifestation" means. Please remember that terminology and notation is not uniform and that readers of your question have no context except that which you give them.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Yes, but the papers rarely discussed it, rather, focused on the differential equations, etc. It was unclear why that was the case. There's a duality relating $b\rightarrow 1/b$, so does changing the lattice going to affect the partition function if $\mu$ were not adjusted? i.e. instead of the free theory $Z(\tau)=Z(g\tau)$, use $Z(\tau,\mu)=Z(g\tau, g\mu)$?

Comment: Conformal field theories only "have modular invariance" because we typically require them to have modular invariance. For CFTs with an *a priori* definition, this needs to be proven. This proof was done in https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.4296 for Liouville theory.